# java server side processing of a sting and parallel processing

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am new to Java and would like to accept a String that contains StockMarket detail. If the existing string contains a buy order of a script, find a seller for the given price. If there is no match available, add the new order to existing buy order queue.

These needs to be done as fast as possible or preferrably parallely so the given application can process as many orders as possible in least amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of accepting a String,if possible accept a JSON or XML and convert that into an object named StockMarket. --> You will find plenty of libraries on the net for doing this for you and your code will be clean and manageable.

2) Faster processing is a subjective matter and depends on how you code. If you can post some code that you have tried, we can check if any performance optimization is possible.

3) You must be having a method under a class which handles the stated logic. If the method doesn't modify any class level variable, then you can easily parallelize the method calls. Else, you need to put the code snippet where the class level variable(s) are modified in a "synchronized" block. And then parallelization should not be a problem.

Comment: To add to Hirak's answer, If you want to process parallely in java, you would want to read about Threads and concurrency. You can read about it in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Thanks Hirak and Anirudh. I have created objects as suggested by you. But, my concern is with maintaining a Order List [Buy Order List and Sell Order List] of Stocks orders that are entered in the system. Once a order enters the system, parse it, check if there is a match. If yes, execute it[reduce buy or sell quantity resp], else maintain an order Que [Buy order List, Sell Order List] . Hence was wondering how to maintain the said order queue and if possible process it parallely while parser is parsing next order that has entered system. Thanks again

Comment: So this is not a queue as per FIFO characteristic. In order to achieve the stated functionality, have a Data object that contains two "static" Lists. One for buy and one for sell. Whenever an order executes, just add a new element to the buy list or remove one element from the sell list. Let me know if that helps. 
P.S:Once you are through this step, consider making the Data object immutable.

Comment: Thanks Hirak. The Buy/Sell List needs to contain Price list and needs to have a Value for it. Hence I am using HashMap here. The value with contain "OrderQty" and "OrderId" so I am using ArrayList<Order> where Order contains "OrderQty and OrderId. Hence it will be a BuyHashMap and SellHashMap that contains value as ArrayList<Order>. Now, my only concern is how do I make Order execution parallel while the parser is parsing the received request. I will add more details for clarity: The app has to receive incoming request, parse it and send to Match server, which checks if order can be executed"

Comment: How is your application invoked?
1)if this is a web application then it is automatically parallel processing.
2)If you have a standalone application, which is scheduled and where requests are passed to your main class through commandline, then you have to schedule the same main multiple times in your scheduler.
3)If you have a standlone application where the main class reads the requests from file/DB, then you need to multithread your application. For multi threading, if you are using Java 7, you can use Form-Join api.

Comment: Thanks @Hirak. Is there a way to upvote your answer ?  You are right, APP reads from file. For ArrayList<Object> that is used as value of HashMap, I want to check if ArrayList is right choice. The OrderQty can reduce and hence its value needs to be modified. Order, O1 that has 100 qty needs to be executed first. It can reduce to 50 , 40.. However, till the time its value becomes 0, I cannot use Order O2

Comment: Well ArrayList can be used.. yes. And if your problem is answered you might as well accept my answer :) cheers